# Hide field by combo value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have two fields in a form. One is a drop-down list with 4 values ​​and another is a text field. I'm trying to perform a control to hide the free text field when I load the form with data and that record I choose has a value from the drop-down list in particular. The problem is that I do half of it since it returns the data but I have to select a random value from the list so that the text field disappears. When I choose another value from the list, it returns empty data from the text field.

```
    <div id="caja" class="formularios ico_esq_especies">



    <h2>Alta nombre sinónimo del taxon <i>Lynx pardinus (Temminck, 1827)</i></h2>   


<form id="modificaNombreSinonimoForm" action="#" method="post">
    <input name="idTUsuarios" id="idTUsuarios" value="0" type="hidden">
    <input name="scientificname" id="scientificname" value="Lynx pardinus (Temminck, 1827)" type="hidden">
    <input name="pagPrev" id="pagPrev" value="" type="hidden">
    <input name="idTaxon" id="idTaxon" value="" type="hidden">
    <input name="scientificnameid" id="scientificnameid" value="11943" type="hidden">


    <div id="f_2colselect">
        <span class="tx_slect">Status:</span><br>
            <div class="styled-select">
            <select id="idtaxonomicstatus" name="idtaxonomicstatus">
                <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
                <option class="select" value="0">Desconocido</option><option class="select" value="1" selected="selected">Aceptado/Válido</option><option class="select" value="2">Sinonímia</option><option class="select" value="3">Ambiguo</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="f_2col">Identificador del taxon:
        <input id="acceptednameusageid" name="acceptednameusageid" value="11943" style="display: none;" type="text">
    </p>

    <p>* indica campo obligatorio</p>

        <div id="botones">
            <input id="guardarNombreSinonimo" class="bt_derecha" value="Guardar" type="button">
            <input id="volver" class="bt_izquierda" value="Volver" type="button">
        </div>

</form>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#idtaxonomicstatus").change(function(){
        var opcion = $(this).val();
        if (opcion == "1" || opcion == "-1")
           $("#acceptednameusageid").hide();
        else
           $("#acceptednameusageid").show();
    });

    $("#volver").click(function(){
        var elem = document.createElement('textarea');
        elem.innerHTML = "/portal/site/iepnbPortal/template.PAGE/especies2/?javax.portlet.tpst=ea0cc0146a52b88ecb55b5b5235d20a0&amp;javax.portlet.prp_ea0cc0146a52b88ecb55b5b5235d20a0=idEspecie%26accion%3DverFormConsultaEspeciesFiltrado&amp;javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&amp;javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken";
        window.location.href = elem.value;
    });

    $("#guardarNombreSinonimo").click(function(){

        var error = false;
        var mensajeErrores = "";

    $("#alertas_obligatorias").html("");

        mensajeErrores = "<ul>";

        if($.trim($("#scientificname").val()) == ""){
            $("#scientificname").removeClass("campo_normal").addClass('campo_obligatorio'); 
            mensajeErrores = mensajeErrores+'<li>Campo <i>Nombre Sinónimo</i> es obligatorio</li>';
            error = true;
        }else {
            $("#scientificname").removeClass("campo_obligatorio").addClass("campo_normal");
        }


        if (error){
            mensajeErrores = mensajeErrores+'</ul>';
            $("#alertas_obligatorias").html(mensajeErrores);
            $("#alertas_obligatorias").show('slow');
        }
        if(!error){
            $("#modificaNombreSinonimoForm").attr("action", "/portal/site/iepnbPortal/template.PAGE/action.process/especies2/?javax.portlet.action=true&javax.portlet.tpst=ea0cc0146a52b88ecb55b5b5235d20a0&javax.portlet.prp_ea0cc0146a52b88ecb55b5b5235d20a0=accion%3DguardarNombreSinonimo%26javax.portlet.action%3Daction&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken");
            $("#modificaNombreSinonimoForm").submit();              
        }

    });

    $("#waiting").hide();
});


    showAlert('Mensaje','Guardado correctamente','Aceptar');
```

When I load this record it returns data to me in the `acceptnameusageid` field and should not have that function but return the hidden field `acceptnameusageid` directly if the value of the drop-down list is 1 or Aceptado. When the value change of the list is disappear but not at the beginning.

1-This is the record that the jsp returns on my website.

[image]

2-When I load the data in my form to modify, I do not have to show the text field

[image]

3-If I change the value of the combo it shows me the id of the field, which is what I need

[image]

4-And if I return to the value of the list that interests me so as not to show the text field if it works for me, I should save the passage of the first image and load the text field empty.

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. What problem you are facing with current code?Also can please show the rendered HTML of your browser.This current HTML have codea and hard to understand

Comment: Please change the template code to acutal HTML in the snippet I made for you

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Just add .change: `$("#idtaxonomicstatus").change(function() {
    var opcion = $(this).val();
    if (opcion == "1")
      $("#acceptednameusageid").hide().val("");
    else
      $("#acceptednameusageid").show();
  }).change();` <<<<

Comment: @mplungjan It works but .val ("") does not make sense since it always shows the field empty.Thank you!!

Comment: I did not pay attention to that part. You want to trigger change onload, add .change() to the event handler definition

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, do not explain me well, thank you and have a nice day

Comment: No no, you helped me impeccably